# require function fails at lua_load with SYNTAX ERR

Tags: lua, lua-5.2

I am new to Lua. I have ported Lua 5.2 to another platform. I am able to run Lua scripts.
But have a problem with loading modules.
I have a `sample.lua` script below. In this script I am trying to call a function available in another Lua script using the require function. The require function fails at `lua_load()` with `LUA_ERRSYNTAX`. Not sure if this is problem with Lua 5.2 version.

**sample.lua**

```
require"module"

welcome()
```

**module.lua**

```
function welcome()
    print(" Hello in module")
end
```

The require function in `sample.lua` file locates the `module.lua` file but fails at `lua_load()`. 
Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: `lua_load` pushes an error message on the stack in case of failures. Are you able to retrieve that message?

Comment: What do you mean by *ported*? Lua should compile unmodified in all platforms that have an ANSI C compiler.

Comment: lhf - I might be wrong here in when i mean ported. I ment i have lua5.2  working a device which runs on different OS

Comment: ComicSansMS- It provides me module.lua:1: unexpected symbol near char(195). 
I really dont understand the meaning of this

Answer (score 0):

Could You be more specific about those different OS'es? Firstly, You should compile Lua for exactly the same OS and device Your are running *.lua scripts on. Secondly, You should check module.lua for some weird typos and invisible symbols. String.char(195) doesn't seem very visible. Also, could You check the enconding of that/those two Lua scripts?

Comment: the OS is threadX. I have few lua scripts that run over the same OS. I have compiled the module.lua and found no errors. Can you let me know How to check encoding of lua scripts ?